# Chinese bracket cause "chemmacros" work wrong?

Tags: chemmacros, chinese

The `\ch` command works well in `chemmacros` package, but if there is Chinese bracket after the `\ch` command there is distortion of the symbol before that. Adding a space between them can solve it, but what is the reason?

Please use **XeLaTeX** engine

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros,ctex}
\begin{document}
\ch{^{34}SO2}\par
\isotope*{34,S}\ch{O2}（Chinese bracket）\par
\isotope*{34,S}\ch{O2} （Chinese bracket）
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah subscript position.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. It is the problem about subscript position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the `\interchartoks` feature enters the scene and does weird things.

A hack that seem to solve the problem is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros,ctex}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy\origch\ch
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\ch}{O{}m}{\origch[#1]{#2}\kern0pt\relax}%
}

\begin{document}

\origch{O2}（Chinese bracket）% bad

\ch{O2}（Chinese bracket）% OK

\end{document}
```

Something that should be brought to the attention of the maintainers of `chemmacros` and of `ctex`.

[image]

Comment: I have post the this problem in Github of **chemmacros** and of **ctex**.